# git - use solution from another repository

Tags: c#, git, deployment, project

I have made a small class called "TestHelper" that should be used by our testing team to better write Tests. Currently my project is in a public repo.

**Question:** What would be the best practise to enable my coworkers to use the solution?

**2nd Question**: How would I compile my c# project?

Comment: Hi @HardReset, it may have been a long shot, as the question could be expanded to better explain your needs, but I tried writing an answer with a few assumptions (which is never good). I suggest you add more content/description to your question and let me know if my answer is aligned to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Attention - this answer is considering the use of Visual Studio and other Microsoft development tools**

The most common approach would be to use [NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget): a mechanism through which developers can create, share, and consume useful code in packages.

Compiling the code and creating a NuGet package is as simple and the process for doing so is already integrated into the Visual Studio tool. So, it is basically configuring the project and clicking Pack and explained in [Microsoft's tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli).